# String replacement with LIKE and %

Tags: sql, sql-server

my Settings table has 2 columns: Key, Value. Both are strings.
What I am trying to do is finding a smart way to create one single SQL statement that changes the string inside Value according to what's inside.
For example, Value can contain:

'wo, find, search'

OR

'find, wo, search'

OR

'find, search, wo'

What I want to do in all 3 cases is using one SQL script to replace 'wo' with an empty string. What I created so far is:

```
update Settings set Value = replace(Value, 'wo, ', '') 
where Key = 'SelectFeature'
update Settings set Value = replace(Value, ', wo', '') 
where Key = 'SelectFeature'
update Settings set Value = replace(Value, 'wo', '') 
where Key = 'SelectFeature'
```

as you can see it's not very elegant. Can I somehow use the operator LIKE and % to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You know that you also replace `, Wonka` with `nka`. Your requirement is strange and prone of errors and a LIKE won't help you. It seems you are storing multiple informations in one column. That' s the core of the problem. Comma separated values belong into their own table, one in it's own record and all referenced via foreign key. Then it's easy to delete `wo`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter unfortunately it has to stay like this for now because it's some old legacy code.. but I totally agree with you. Won't happen the scenario of ,Wonka

Comment: Don't store multiple values in a single string.  Then you won't have problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not the best solution but a more optimal way would be to do

```
UPDATE
    Settings
SET
    Value = REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(Value, 'wo, ', ''), ', wo', ''
        ), 'wo', ''
    )
WHERE
    Key = 'SelectFeature'
```

This way you only run one query where you do all the changes... Update queries cost a lot of process time...